# Togglz using FallbackTestFeatureManager in CucumberTest with Spring Boot & Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cucumber, togglz

we are using Togglz Kotlin in a Spring Boot 2.7.5 Project.
We followed the example in Github using a MongoStateRepository and everything works fine.

Now for some reason in the Cucumber Test, in the logs I can see our feature Manager is being created and the feature toggles are initialy being writen to MongoDB. For some reason though, in the application the FallbackTestFeatureManager is being used. I can see it in the isActive Method of the Feature Enum.

We are not using any extra Cucumber config file, the application.yaml has an entry to enable togglz.

Any help, hint appreciated.

We our using the
togglz-spring-boot-starter,
togglz-security-spring-boot-starter,
togglz-console-spring-boot-starter,
togglz-kotlin,
togglz-mongodb,
togglz-testing  -> scope test
dependencies